# Program to graph MySQL data

Tags: mysql, graph

I have a fairly simple mysql database. I want to extract data from it and display as a graph to analyze it. Nothing advanced, just line diagrams and such. As a programmer I can always write some code for this myself. But does anybody know of a program that can load data (using sql queries?) and display it in various graphs?

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [DBPlot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbplot/) for Windows environment.

Comment: Yes. I thinks dbplot is perfectly fit for this question.

Comment: @MarianKlühspies for large dataset, you probably want to use FastLine or FastPoint chart type.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at [**Google Charts**](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/), if you want your graphs displayed in web pages.

Comment: This is what' I'm planning to use if I can't find an application to help me out. Seems simple to use, but still you need to program it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what type of output you're looking for, but FusionCharts has helped me a lot... http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GNUPLOT](http://www.gnuplot.info/) if you are in linux environment. I am currently using this for generating automated EOD reports which contains graphs. The graphs are drawn using the data fetched from mysql (Currently we are using in csv) But gnuplot is not as good as Fusion Chart in UI Perspective

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to recommend JQplot if you want these graphs in web pages - it's non Flash (hooray!), uses JQUery (hooray!) and has some very, very cool features (hooray! - check out the examples page).

As per [the docs page](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html), you can just pass an array of values to it and it'll plot what you want, and generating an array is simple in server side languages such as PHP.

Hope this helps,

James

Comment: Looks very nice, but I'm and looking for a program that can do simple graphs for me, so I don't have to program it myself.

Comment: @Biggles: Are you looking to do it on the web, or can you use an offline program such as OpenOffice Sheet?

Comment: I was looking for an offline program. I finally settled for Google Charts though, since I could find anything else.

Comment: Ah. Good to hear you've found a solution. Sorry I couldn't be of much help :-)

Answer (score 0):

An extremely flexible library for graphs (images and applets) would be [JFreeChart](http://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/&ei=G2egUJi5JKiP0AXS7oHoDg&usg=AFQjCNH4szIUMolJWcCHWoIFaRxLiDaBGQ&sig2=WvJfS_gvz_bDSGxIDt1_xQ).
On the other hand, if what you actually need it is a reporting engine, [Jasperreports](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%204.8.0/) should be your first and final stop but you will have to do A LOT of reading before starting doing something with the latter and it won't be time lost for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Smart chart maker](http://mysqlreports.com/mysql-reporting-tools/mysql-chart-maker/) it is used to create many type of charts that can be fed from a MySQL database . supported chart types include line charts , pie charts, bar charts, and scattered charts. 
[image]

Comment: well, I didn't need to write any code, smart chart maker has a wizard style interface that let you connect to the database, then visually set the data you want to show in each axis, data - filter (if any) , set appearance settings  then it display the dynamic / auto update chart that you can easily embed in any web page .